# Seaborn: How to temporarily replace none-numeric values in a column with a numeric values for distribution?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, seaborn

This may sound like a strange question, but I was wondering if it's possible to temporarily replace none-numeric values in a column with numeric values, so that we can see the distribution.

Only because, if we use the `distplot` function, it only works for numerical values only, not none-numeric values.

Therefore, consider the sample data I have (shown below).

```
ID     Colour
---------------
1       Red     
---------------     
2       Red
---------------
3       Blue
---------------
4       Red
---------------
5       Blue
---------------
```

Would it be possible to temporarily replace "Red" and "Blue" with numerical values? For example: replacing "Red" with 1 and "Blue" with 0.

Hence, by replacing the none-numeric values (Red and Blue) with numeric values (1 and 0), it would allow me to generate a distribution plot to see the density of "Red" and "Blue" in my dataset.

Therefore, how would I achieve this, so that I can see the distribution and density of Red and Blue colours in my dataset using a `distplot`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the sample data:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = ({"Colour": [Red, Red, Blue, Red, Blue]})
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df
  Colour
0    Red
1    Red
2   Blue
3    Red
4   Blue
```

You can then create a `colour_map` for the values:

```
>>> colour_map = {'Red': 1, 'Blue': 0}
```

Then, by applying `.map()` against the column:

```
>>> df['Colour'] = df['Colour'].map(colour_map)
```

Result:

```
>>> df
   Colour
0       1
1       1
2       0
3       1
4       0
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I tried it, but my result dataframe just seems to be replaced with NaN values for some reason. Not sure what has happened.

Comment: I seem to get this error: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: Perhaps, you can try to add anew col by colour with this `df['Colour_Map'] = df['Colour'].map(colour_map)` so the original values are not overwritten which are to be plotted.

Comment: Just tried it - still getting NaN values in the new column too.

Comment: Hmm, really not sure. Maybe you can check if your data has any leading or training spaces?

Comment: It works now. I had a double space somewhere. Apologies.